# What does "peu encombrantes" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I'm reading a text which discusses "Industrial installations" and read the following sentence:

> Ces installations industrielles sont **peu encombrantes** mais ...

According to Larousse's definition of "[*encombrant*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/encombrant/29100)" :

> 1. Bulky, cumbersome
> 2. Inhibiting, awkward

It seems to me "peu encombrantes" in this sentence has another meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ces installations industrielles sont peu encombrantes mais ...

Une installation industrielle nécessite de l'espace et occupe un volume : on pense d'habitude aux fonderies, aux industries de l'automobile ou pétrolières.

C'est la notion de *volume* qui est ici évoquée, si *ces installations industrielles sont peu encombrantes*, c'est qu'elles ne nécessitent pas l'usage d'une zone industrielle importante, mais qu'elles peuvent être exercées dans des bâtiments plus restreints, comme ceux des industries horlogères, ou celles qui fabriquent des très petites pièces détachées.

Dans cette phrase, le *volume* de ces installations n'a rien à voir avec *importune*, elles ne sont pas importunes mais peu volumineuses.

En revanche, si elles sont polluantes, elles peuvent importuner leurs voisins, mais la phrase ne serait pas écrite de cette manière, le mot *encombrant* n'aurait pas été utilisé.